# React. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправлялось сообщение в телеграмм

Tags: reactjs, telegram-bot

У меня есть 2 инпута, value которых я хочу отправлять сообщение в телеграмм. И все это должно происходить по нажатию кнопки. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

В телеграмм можно отправить сообщение из телеграмма.Тебе придется или найти чей-то или написать собственный API (например на Node.js)